# How to aggregate over 'ip' field using script

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate

I am trying to perform terms aggregation over a field of type 'ip' using inline script like this :

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "by_ipaddress": {
            "terms": {
                "script": {
                    "inline": "doc['ipAddressFrom'].value",
                    "lang": "painless"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It throws following exception :

```
"reason": {
                "type": "script_exception",
                "reason": "runtime error",
                "caused_by": {
                    "type": "array_index_out_of_bounds_exception",
                    "reason": "16"
                },
                "script_stack": [
                    "org.apache.lucene.util.UnicodeUtil.UTF8toUTF16(UnicodeUtil.java:602)",
                    "org.apache.lucene.util.BytesRef.utf8ToString(BytesRef.java:152)",
                    "org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.ScriptDocValues$Strings.getValue(ScriptDocValues.java:83)",
                    "doc['ipAddressFrom'].value",
                    "                    ^---- HERE"
                ],
                "script": "doc['ipAddressFrom'].value",
                "lang": "painless"
            }
```

But when I aggregate over the same field :

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "by_ipaddress": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "ipAddressFrom"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works.

Mapping for the field "ipAddressFrom" is :

```
 "ipAddressFrom" : {
    "type" : "ip"
}
```

Please let me know how to use ip fields in script.

Answer (score 1):

For elasticsearch 6.x, there is nothing wrong with using `ip` type in painless scripts.

Your aggregation with `inline` doesn't work because for some documents field `ipAddressFrom` does not exist.

You can fix the aggregation with something like:

```
 "script": {
      "inline": "if (doc.containsKey('ipAddressFrom') && !doc['ipAddressFrom'].empty){ return doc['ipAddressFrom'].value} else {return '0'}",
      "lang": "painless"
    }
```

Comment: Our scheme is such that, this field will always have a non-null value. I confirmed this too by running 'exists' query.

Comment: What version of Elasticsearch are you running? I've tested your script with 6.2.3 version and the results are the same with the simple aggregation. (In my case, all documents have that ip field)

Comment: I am using 5.1.1.

Comment: They had a bug until es 5.2 regarding handling ips in scripts. See https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/22584

Comment: ohhk, that' helpful. For now, I am considering to change the mapping for the field as to use multi-fields : "{
                "type" : "keyword",
                "fields" : {
                  "keyword" : {
                    "type" : "ip"
                  }
                }
              }"